# The following assertion was thrown building Builder: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build?

Tags: mysql, flutter

iam new to flutter but really i dont see what is the error in my code it first it keeps showing that :
The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
and when i hot relod this comes up
line 4016 pos 12: '!_debugLocked':
is not true.
i dont know what to do and why this is happening because its the first time

```
class _RepresentativeUiState extends State<RepresentativeUi> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  // navy bottom pages
  final _newsFeedPage = RNewsFeed();
  final _profilePage = RProfile();
  final _addPostPage = RAddPost();
  final _libraryPage = RLibrary();
  Widget _showPage = RNewsFeed();
  Widget _pageChooser(int page) {
    switch (page) {
      case 0:
        return _newsFeedPage;
        break;
      case 1:
        return _addPostPage;
        break;
      case 2:
        return _libraryPage;
        break;
      case 3:
        return _profilePage;
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        index: _currentIndex,
        items: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.newspaper,
            size: 30,
          ),
          Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
            size: 30,
          ),
          Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.book,
            size: 30,
          ),
          Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.user,
            size: 30,
          ),
        ],
        color: Colors.white,
        buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff131535),
        animationCurve: Curves.easeIn,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        onTap: (int tappedIndex) {
          setState(() {
            _showPage = _pageChooser(tappedIndex);
          });
        },
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: _showPage,
      ),
    );
  }
}



class RNewsFeed extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RNewsFeedState createState() => _RNewsFeedState();
}

class _RNewsFeedState extends State<RNewsFeed> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text('1'),
    );
  }
}

class RAddPost extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RAddPostState createState() => _RAddPostState();
}

class _RAddPostState extends State<RAddPost> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text('2'),
    );
  }
}

class RLibrary extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RLibraryState createState() => _RLibraryState();
}

class _RLibraryState extends State<RLibrary> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text('3'),
    );
  }
}

class RProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RProfileState createState() => _RProfileState();
}


class _RProfileState extends State<RProfile> {
  String _name ;
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((value) => {
      setState((){
        value.getString('name');
      })
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff131535),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50,
              ),
              Text(
                '$_name',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the culprit i believe:

```
SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((value) => {
  setState((){
    value.getString('name');
  })
});
```

There's no need to ever call `setState()` in `initState()`. So what happens now is that while the page is building, `setState()` is trying to initiate another build process. Simply remote the setState wrapper around `value.getString('name');`.

Comment: even if i delete the whole statement the error appears again

Comment: can you give me a code of what should i do exactly ?

Comment: I really can't because that's the only setState() i see. There might be something wrong in the other classes you call.

Comment: so in your opinion i should remove it  ?

Comment: Yes, never use `setState()` in `initState()`

Comment: and when i do i get some error that i dont understand it tells me that 
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: Builder
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///C:/Users/fahmi/Desktop/msc_mu/lib/main.dart:29:10
and that is my main function why is that  ?

Comment: Also, this is changed in `initState()` so a hot reload i not enough. You have to re-run the code whenever you change something in `initState()`

Comment: yah but i cant provide pictures here do you have discord if you have time ?

Comment: No need for a picture. Just paste the error codes here that arent from the framework but from your own classes. Normally they are at the top or the error chain.

Comment: The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
process of building widgets.A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase
only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework
builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase

Comment: Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#8c10b]
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
  Builder

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  MaterialApp file:///C:/Users/fahmi/Desktop/msc_mu/lib/main.dart:29:10

Comment: sorry for late reply